# Is there a way to verify what argument new is called with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm trying to write a unit test for the following snippet, to verify that the URL is created correctly according to some logic.

```
URL = '/abc/def?param1=val1' # some logic to create URL
http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(URL))
```

When I stubbed http object with Minitest and did a

```
expect :request, "some response", [EXPECTED_URL]
```

Minitest complains that the arguments don't match.
`MockExpectationError: mocked method :request called with unexpected arguments [#<Net::HTTP::Get GET>]`
The argument is of type Net::HTTP::Get GET
and when I step through the minitest code and compare the GET body they are indeed the same,

```
(byebug) args[0].to_yaml
"--- !ruby/object:Net::HTTP::Get\nmethod: GET\nrequest_has_body: false\nresponse_has_body: true\nuri: \npath: \"ACTUAL_URL\"\ndecode_content: true\nheader:\n  accept-encoding:\n  - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\n  accept:\n  - \"*/*\"\n  user-agent:\n  - Ruby\nbody: \nbody_stream: \nbody_data: \n"
(byebug) expected_args[0].to_yaml
"--- !ruby/object:Net::HTTP::Get\nmethod: GET\nrequest_has_body: false\nresponse_has_body: true\nuri: \npath: \"EXPECTED_URL\"\ndecode_content: true\nheader:\n  accept-encoding:\n  - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\n  accept:\n  - \"*/*\"\n  user-agent:\n  - Ruby\nbody: \nbody_stream: \nbody_data: \n"
```

however "==" and "===" tests don't return true and
Minitest assertion of the expected call fails.
I thought stubbing new and comparing the parameter being passed might be another approach but not sure what would be the syntax for it and couldn't find any minitest relevant examples for the same. Has anyone done something similar in the past?

Comment: I would use webmock instead which lets you test that a http request is sent instead of testing the implementation details which will just break the test if you refactor the code.

Comment: Thanks - testing with webmock sounds like a good alternative.